# What happens if a party to a contract is purchased?

Tags: contract-law

If there's a contract between parties X and Y, and Y is bought by Z, then what happens to that contract? Is it automatically as if the contract was between X and Z? Or instead, do X and Z need to negotiate a replacement contract?